# AjaxControlToolkit AutoCompleteExtender not working in IIS

Tags: c#, iis-6, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I am using the AjaxControlToolkit's AutoCompleteExtender without a Web Service(PageMethod). **It is working fine on my local machine, but AutoCompleteExtender won't work in the IIS although AjaxControlToolkit does.**

I've searched around but none applies to my problem.

It is running in IIS-6, and Framework 4.0.

Heres my code:

ASP

```
<!-- Auto Suggestion --><ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="ajaxAutoCompleteEmpNo" 
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
    TargetControlID="txtEmpNo" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    CompletionInterval="100" 
    CompletionSetCount="10" >
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Code Behind: C#

```
// Auto complete method
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
{

    List<string> strResult = new List<string>();
    OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csdbETSMain"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT EmpNo FROM dbetsmain.tblusers WHERE EmpNo LIKE ? LIMIT ?", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("EmpNo",OdbcType.VarChar, 4).Value = prefixText + '%';
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Limit", OdbcType.Int).Value = count;

    OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        strResult.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }


    return strResult.ToArray();
}
```

Please help, thank you.

UPDATE:

There is no error display. The suggestion list doesn't appear.

More info about the [AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx)

Comment: Please specify exactly _how_ it's "not working."

Comment: Can you call the WebMethod directly (with Fiddler or some other TestClient)? Does it work then? Can you run it in Debug mode?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - I've updated my original post.

Comment: @NeilThompson - I'll test later, will provide update.

Comment: Use try catch on your code behind so that the uncatch error of the clr will be displayed,

Answer (score -1):

Try...this

go to start>run>inetmgr>

In the connections sidepane..select application pools

select the application pool that u hav assigned when deployed that project into iis(to check that go to sites>in connections pane...and right click on website that u have deployed and select manage website >advanced settings then at the top u wil able to see application pool)

then comeback and select that particular application pool in application pools in connections pane right click on that particular application pool and select advanced settings..find out process model in that and select identity and browse through it and goto built in account and select local system.......then click ok...and get out of it...

I think it will work..it worked for me.....